# sasl mechanism using librdkafka in RHEM

Tags: http-proxy

how to configure sasl mechanism using kerberos in librdkafka library in RHEM OS.

I have already set:

```
WITH_SASL =y
```

Installed the libsasl2 package

Comment: Do you mean RHEL OS?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. I'm guessing you are on RHEL so make sure to install the following packages first: `cyrus-sasl cyrus-sasl-devel cyrus-sasl-gssapi`
2. Then run `./configure` from the librdkafka directory, check the output and make sure it lists `WITH_SASL          y`.
3. Run `make` and `sudo make install`
4. Find out what port the broker's SASL_PLAINTEXT listener is listening on by either asking your Kafka ops team or by looking at the `listeners=..` configuration property in the broker's server.properties file.
5. Follow the steps outlined in this Wiki post to set up keytabs, etc: https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/wiki/Using-SASL-with-librdkafka
6. Verify that it works with one of the example programs, e.g: `examples/rdkafka_example -b <broker>:<sasl_port> -L -d security -X security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT -X sasl.kerberos.service.name=<service> -X sasl.kerberos.keytab=/path/to/clients.keytab -X sasl.kerberos.principle=<clientname>/<clienthost>`
7. When you have it working with the example program, move the configuration properties into your program (`rd_kafka_conf_set()` et.al)

Also see the more detailed SASL documentation here:
http://docs.confluent.io/3.1.1/kafka/sasl.html

Comment: Thenks a lot for such a description.. i followed evry steps except running in example program and checking..

Comment: SASL key refresh failed: /usr/bin/kinit -S "kafka/hdfs500.host.mobistar.be" -k -t " cgnkafka@HADOOPACC.HOST.MOBISTAR.BE: exited with code 1
%7|1484897977.990|SASL|rdkafka#producer-1| sasl_plaintext://hdfs500.host.mobistar.be:9092/bootstrap: Available SASL mechanisms: GSS-SPNEGO GSSAPI
%2|1484897978.002|LIBSASL|rdkafka#producer-1| sasl_plaintext://hdfs500.host.mobistar.be:9092/bootstrap: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.